# Universal Analytics - Multi-author report, custom dimensions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, universal-analytics

I am upgrading from Classic analytics to UA so my question relates to the tracking code that I need. There are several additional custom dimensions (e.g author) that I want to also use.

Not every page on the site would have an author but there are many articles that would.

My question is if i need to duplicate the `ga('send', 'pageview')` but pass the author variable as below:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'example.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': '<?=$author?>'});
</script>
```

Comment: Where about's did you find the documentation i can't find it anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should send a single pageview. Otherwise the pageview data will be duplicated in GA.

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'example.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': '<?=$author?>'});
</script>
```

Comment: Aren't you sending two pageview too?

Comment: @Blexy, fixed. Sorry about that oversight.

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo. This leads me to a couple of questions: Do i need to add all authors as custom dimensions and the above code will track them? Have about the code for tracking events? For example, tracking errors on a form: ga('send', 'Event', 'Signup Form', 'First Name', 'Error Code Desc', {'nonInteraction': 1}”                      Is this put in the tracking code too? Or in the code for the form?

Comment: @Ninjasys I'm not sure I understand the followup questions. You should accept this answer and ask a new question, feel free to add the link here for this follow up.